# Check if response is a stream or json

Tags: node.js, request

How can I check if response from http post request, using the request module, is json format or stream?

```
request({
            uri: proxy_url,
            method: req.route.method,
            body: req.params.file
        }, (err, resp, body) => {
            if (err)
                console.log(err)

            if (body == Stream)
                //write to file
            else {
                console.log(body)
            }
        })
```

Comment: By the way everything sent over http is streamed . It is only on the receiving side that we get a json.

Comment: ok. how can I distinguish whether it is json or an image stream?

Comment: you should rather check the content type of the request, for json it would be application/json and for image type it would be an image type.